# How to run ussd code using startActivityForResult inside a for loop

Tags: for-loop, start-activity, ussd, startactivityforresult

```
final String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
for(int j=1; j<10;j=j+2) {
```

//I Wanted to Execute the Ussd Code in a Loop but "Connection problem or invalid MMI code." is displayed

//But if i take the for loop out the ussd code will be executed once... but i wanted it to be executed more than once

```
startActivityForResult(
     new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
         + "*" + 804 + encodedHash)), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   try {
      for(int j=1; j<10;j=j+2){
      startActivityForResult(
      new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
      + "*" + 804 + encodedHash)), 1);
}
Thread.sleep(15000);
}
finish();
} catch (Exception eExcept) {
}}}).start();
```